# Getting dictionary key values in django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

I have a dictionary created with Counter() in django. I have a list named studentlist. I fill this list with some elements. Then i get the repeating elements number with Counter().

In my view :

```
    studentlist = []
    for stu in studentslatetoclassthissemester:
        student = str(stu['student__std_no'])
        studentlist.append(student)

    studentsum = Counter(studentlist)
```

So studentsum is a dictionary as below.

> Counter({'0247': 4, '0044': 1, '0050': 1, '0241': 1, '0854': 1, '0245': 1, '0076': 1, '0234': 1})

In the django template i am trying to get specifi key and values as below :

```
{% for key, value in studentsum.items %}                  
    {{key}} - {{value}}                  
{% endfor %}
```

But i get below error :

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: How did you pass the the `studentsum` to the view?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Where are you getting that error?

Comment: I have the impression that you perhaps *change* `studentsum` *in* the template, so that in a second iteration, something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks. It is solved with dict() as below. In the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this in view

```
studentsum = Counter(studentlist)
```

to

```
studentsum = dict(Counter(studentlist))
```

Comment: A counter is a *subclass* of a `dict`ionary, so normally it should work with a `Counter` as well.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when i used dict() as in this answer.